# How can I save my listView with Shared Preferences in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences, countdowntimer

I have edittext, countdowntimer, listview , shared preferences on my project. My app can work. my countdown timer on finish I add text my listview. and I save this with shared preferences. And if I open new countdown timer after finish It add new text to listview but It save only last text How can ı save all text in ListView .

```
 public class pomodoro extends AppCompatActivity {
        Button baslat,backhome,bitir;
            EditText edittextcalisma,edittextmola;
            CountDownTimer calisma,mola;
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
            ListView listView;
        
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_pomodoro);
                 LoadPreferences();
              
                listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listv);
                arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        this,R.layout.list_view,R.id.textitem, list);
                listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                bitir=findViewById(R.id.bitirbutton);
                baslat = findViewById(R.id.baslatbutton);
                edittextcalisma = findViewById(R.id.edittextcalisma);
                edittextmola = findViewById(R.id.edittextmola);
               
                baslat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
        
                        closeKeyboard();
        
                        final int molapo = Integer.valueOf(edittextmola.getText().toString());
                        final int calismapo = Integer.valueOf(edittextcalisma.getText().toString());
        
                       
 CountDownTimer bekle = new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onTick(long millis) {
        
        
                                                }
                                                @Override
                                                public void onFinish() {
                                                    
                                                    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                                                    SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy HH:mm");
                                                    String datetime = dateformat.format(c.getTime());
        
        
        
                                                    list.add("Çalışma Süresi : " + calismapo +"  dk  "+"\n"+  "Mola Süresi : " + molapo+"  dk  " +"\n" + datetime);
                                                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                                                                                                          SavePreferences("LISTS", task);
        
        
                                                }
                                            }.start();
                                        }
                                    }.start();
                                }
                            }.start();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }                                                                                                                                                                                                                  protected void SavePreferences(String key, String value) {
         
            SharedPreferences data = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data.edit();
            editor.putString(key, value);
            editor.commit();
    
    
        }
    
        protected void LoadPreferences(){
            SharedPreferences data = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            String dataSet = data.getString("LISTS", "");
    
            list.add(dataSet);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    
        }
        }
```

Comment: you cannot save a view into the shared preferences. Bu you can save the basic primitice data into it. This data may only be the type of primitives like boolean, int, long and String. What do you want to save other than the list view itself? You may want to save the content of the list view as key - value pairs into the shared preferences.

Comment: If the data is tiny, you could store the data in JSON format in SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shared preferences allow you to store small amounts of primitive data as key/value pairs in a file on the device. If you want to Store a list or large amount of data use local database with Room.

[Learn More About Room persistence Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room)

Comment: How can I store my list with Room Persistence Library

Comment: fallow this code lab this will help you to learn about room Database https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view#0 this code lab is provided by google